How reliable is the floppy content listing information on a C64?
According to this answer, directory listings are generated by the C64 disk drive on the fly:

The disk drive creates a pseudo-BASIC-program when the C64 reads from a file named "$".

This implies that you cannot fake the content on a disk, because you have no way to make the drive display fake content, since you have no control over the code that does the listening, not without first loading a program that patches the code on the drive.
Now please take a look at the following content listing of a demo disk:

All files on that disk are zero blocks in size and still you can perform a LOAD"*",8,1 and the first file can be loaded and executed? How can this be? How can you lie about file size? The first file certainly is not zero blocks in size.
Is the file size stored explicitly as a numeric value and you can easily lie about it, since the loading operation won't care for that numeric value and just follow the linked list of blocks?
And what other values could you lie about? File type (PRG)? Blocks free? Is any information relevant at all or is the only relevant information the first block on disk for every file and that's all the loading code will ever care for?

It's been a while, but I remember that kind of directory listings as being pretty common in C64 days.

When a file is loaded, the drive will read the starting block indicated in the directory entry; if the first byte of a read block is non-zero, it will output the last 254 bytes and then read the block identified by the first two bytes, interpreted as track and sector numbers.  Otherwise it will output the number of bytes indicated by the second byte and stop.  The only way for a drive to know how big a file actually is would be to read every block of it.  The size indication in the directory listing is maintained as a convenience, but isn't actually used for any purpose other than to show the listing.
File names are stored padded with "shifted space" characters.  When showing a listing, the first shifted space character will be shown as a quote mark, and everything else will show as normal.  This allows for directory listings to include text beyond the closing quote.  Further, the file-name matching algorithm would report a match if all specified characters matched and the next character was a shifted space.  This meant that if a file name of ten characters or less could be followed by [shifted space],8,1:, it would appear as
0    "FILENAME"  ,8,1: PRG

and putting the cursor to the left of the name and hitting shift-space would auto-type LOAD[return]RUN[return].  The LOAD command would use the indicated filename and [if necessary] the RUN command would run the file.  Files not needing ,1 could have an extra two characters in the useful part of the name.
Control characters other than delete (20 decimal) will appear as inverse-video characters if between quotes, but will perform their assigned function outside of quotes.
When loading a file, the drive will stop scanning the directory as soon as a suitable file is identified.  Otherwise it will load sequential blocks of directory information similar to the way it loads sequential blocks of files.  A disk may be written so the directory is arbitrarily long, or so that it loops, without affecting attempts to load a file that is successfully found.
The "PRG" label is fetched from a table of file types indexed by a byte in the directory entry.  Vorpal Disk Utilities uses an out-of-range value that shows up as a file type of "SR?", but I'm unaware of any other values showing anything interesting.

The directory lists file names, among others. Creative use in file names of SHIFT-SPACE (which, when LISTed, will appear as a double quote, causing an early disabling of the "quote mode" enabled by the automatically created beginning double quote), cursor control characters, text color control characters, DEL characters, INS characters and such, will pretty much allow you to manipulate the displayed listing in almost any way you like. For some of that stuff you would probably need a sector editor to pull it off, but it is possible.

Ah right... I keep forgetting that you can always use those control characters on Commodore computers to pretty much manipulate whatever text is printed to screen. I didn't consider that you can also use them inside file names.
